# How do I send coins over personal blockchain?

Tags: transactions, wallets, rpc

What I have done --> I have created my own blockchain which is basically forked from Ethereum. So everything that can be done on Ethereum, can in theory by done on my blockchain. I can run a local node on my device.

What I Want to do --> Create two accounts using the browser front end and some JavaScript libraries like web3.js and store its keystore file on my device locally. I want to send coins from one account to another.

Will it be possible to run a local node and connecting to that node using 
`web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost"));`

How do I view/verify the transactions being sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're on track!

Just a bit of terminology first, the node that you're running would be classified as a local node/ local (or private) network, and yes, it will replicate the behaviors of Ethereum mainnet (in most cases).

**A tip**: Don't forget to allocate balance to yourself when setting up your own node in the genesis.json file. It'll be your (test)ether on your own private network.

Yes, `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:port"));` will connect you to your local node. Don't miss the **port number**.

You'd send transactions like you'd on the Ethereum mainnet. The web3js is 'network-agnostic'. Here's the documentation [link](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html) for reference.

> How do I view/verify the transactions being sent?

There are multiple ways. You may use web3js itself and subscribe to [events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html). The easiest way would be to use the node of your console i.e. geth/parity console to check transactions. Additionally, at the moment, our ethereum stackexchange has many answers and amply covers the topic of viewing and verifying transactions.